# PNR generating issue using amadeus flight create orders API

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, amadeus

I want to create booking and generate PNR using amadeus flight booking API.
I have follow 3 step to create booking and generate PNR

1. Flight Offers Search API using bellow API

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference

2. Flight Offers Price API using bellow API

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price/api-reference

3. Flight Create Orders API using bellow API

https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-create-orders/api-reference

When i serach with city with one way thip and choose specific offer and puting passenger details
to create booking and generat PNR. then PNR will generate successfully
i am using bellow API to generate PNR

```
  https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-create-orders/api-reference
```

this is my request json

```
  "data": {
    "type": "flight-order",
    "flightOffers": [
      {
        "type": "flight-offer",
        "id": "5",
        "source": "GDS",
        "instantTicketingRequired": false,
        "nonHomogeneous": false,
        "paymentCardRequired": false,
        "lastTicketingDate": "2021-07-23",
        "itineraries": [
          {
            "segments": [
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "JFK",
                  "terminal": "5",
                  "at": "2021-07-30T09:20:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "FLL",
                  "terminal": "3",
                  "at": "2021-07-30T12:30:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "B6",
                "number": "201",
                "aircraft": {
                  "code": "320"
                },
                "operating": {
                  "carrierCode": "B6"
                },
                "duration": "PT3H10M",
                "id": "91",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "co2Emissions": [
                  {
                    "weight": 155,
                    "weightUnit": "KG",
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "FLL",
                  "terminal": "3",
                  "at": "2021-07-30T16:25:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "LAX",
                  "terminal": "5",
                  "at": "2021-07-30T18:49:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "B6",
                "number": "1301",
                "aircraft": {
                  "code": "32S"
                },
                "operating": {
                  "carrierCode": "B6"
                },
                "duration": "PT5H24M",
                "id": "92",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "co2Emissions": [
                  {
                    "weight": 253,
                    "weightUnit": "KG",
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "duration": "PT12H29M"
          }
        ],
        "price": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "total": "276.20",
          "base": "235.35",
          "fees": [
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "SUPPLIER"
            },
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "TICKETING"
            },
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "FORM_OF_PAYMENT"
            }
          ],
          "grandTotal": "276.20",
          "billingCurrency": "USD"
        },
        "pricingOptions": {
          "fareType": [
            "PUBLISHED"
          ],
          "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false
        },
        "validatingAirlineCodes": [
          "B6"
        ],
        "travelerPricings": [
          {
            "travelerId": "1",
            "fareOption": "STANDARD",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "price": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "276.20",
              "base": "235.35",
              "taxes": [
                {
                  "amount": "8.60",
                  "code": "ZP"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "5.60",
                  "code": "AY"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "17.65",
                  "code": "US"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "9.00",
                  "code": "XF"
                }
              ],
              "refundableTaxes": "40.85"
            },
            "fareDetailsBySegment": [
              {
                "segmentId": "91",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "OL7AUEL1",
                "brandedFare": "DN",
                "class": "L",
                "includedCheckedBags": {
                  "quantity": 0
                }
              },
              {
                "segmentId": "92",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "ZI3PUEL1",
                "brandedFare": "DN",
                "class": "L",
                "includedCheckedBags": {
                  "quantity": 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "travelers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "dateOfBirth": "**********",
        "name": {
          "firstName": "**********",
          "lastName": "**********"
        },
        "gender": "**********"
      }
    ],
    "contacts": [
      {
        "addresseeName": {
          "firstName": "**********",
          "lastName": "**********"
        },
        "purpose": "STANDARD",
        "emailAddress": "**********",
        "phones": [
          {
            "deviceType": "MOBILE",
            "countryCallingCode": "**",
            "number": "**********"
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "**********"
          ],
          "postalCode": "**********",
          "cityName": "**********",
          "countryCode": "**********"
        }
      }
    ],
    "remarks": {
      "general": [
        {
          "subType": "GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS",
          "text": "ONLINE BOOKING FROM INCREIBLE VIAJES"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ticketingAgreement": {
      "option": "DELAY_TO_CANCEL",
      "delay": "6D"
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my API response.
PNR generated successfully/

```
stdClass Object
(
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [status] => 200
                    [code] => 0
                    [title] => ContactInfoSsrNotAddedToBookingWarning
                    [detail] => Unable to create some contact information SSR. Email and mobile phone number required.
                )

        )

    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => flight-order
            [id] => eJzTd9f3cg228PcBAAskAls%3D
            [associatedRecords] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [reference] => JES8OL
                            [creationDate] => 2021-07-23T10:28:00.000
                            [originSystemCode] => GDS
                            [flightOfferId] => 5
                        )

                )

            [flightOffers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [type] => flight-offer
                            [id] => 5
                            [source] => GDS
                            [nonHomogeneous] => 
                            [lastTicketingDate] => 2021-07-23
                            [itineraries] => Array
```

But when i search with differnt city and follow the same step.
this is my request json

```
 data": {
    "type": "flight-order",
    "flightOffers": [
      {
        "type": "flight-offer",
        "id": "3",
        "source": "GDS",
        "instantTicketingRequired": false,
        "nonHomogeneous": false,
        "paymentCardRequired": false,
        "lastTicketingDate": "2021-07-28",
        "itineraries": [
          {
            "segments": [
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "DEL",
                  "terminal": "3",
                  "at": "2021-08-05T05:35:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "BLR",
                  "at": "2021-08-05T08:20:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "AI",
                "number": "803",
                "aircraft": {
                  "code": "32B"
                },
                "operating": {
                  "carrierCode": "AI"
                },
                "duration": "PT2H45M",
                "id": "17",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "co2Emissions": [
                  {
                    "weight": 145,
                    "weightUnit": "KG",
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "duration": "PT2H45M"
          },
          {
            "segments": [
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "BLR",
                  "at": "2021-08-10T17:10:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "DEL",
                  "terminal": "3",
                  "at": "2021-08-10T19:55:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "AI",
                "number": "501",
                "aircraft": {
                  "code": "32B"
                },
                "operating": {
                  "carrierCode": "AI"
                },
                "duration": "PT2H45M",
                "id": "42",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "co2Emissions": [
                  {
                    "weight": 145,
                    "weightUnit": "KG",
                    "cabin": "ECONOMY"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "duration": "PT2H45M"
          }
        ],
        "price": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "total": "88.59",
          "base": "68.00",
          "fees": [
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "SUPPLIER"
            },
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "TICKETING"
            },
            {
              "amount": "0.00",
              "type": "FORM_OF_PAYMENT"
            }
          ],
          "grandTotal": "88.59",
          "billingCurrency": "USD"
        },
        "pricingOptions": {
          "fareType": [
            "PUBLISHED"
          ],
          "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
        },
        "validatingAirlineCodes": [
          "AI"
        ],
        "travelerPricings": [
          {
            "travelerId": "1",
            "fareOption": "STANDARD",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "price": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "88.59",
              "base": "68.00",
              "taxes": [
                {
                  "amount": "6.34",
                  "code": "P2"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "3.78",
                  "code": "IN"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "3.63",
                  "code": "K3"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "2.28",
                  "code": "WO"
                },
                {
                  "amount": "4.56",
                  "code": "YR"
                }
              ],
              "refundableTaxes": "17.19"
            },
            "fareDetailsBySegment": [
              {
                "segmentId": "17",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "SAP8",
                "class": "S",
                "includedCheckedBags": {
                  "weight": 25,
                  "weightUnit": "KG"
                }
              },
              {
                "segmentId": "42",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "SAP8",
                "class": "S",
                "includedCheckedBags": {
                  "weight": 25,
                  "weightUnit": "KG"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "travelers": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "dateOfBirth": "**********",
        "name": {
          "firstName": "**********",
          "lastName": "**********"
        },
        "gender": "**********"
      }
    ],
    "contacts": [
      {
        "addresseeName": {
          "firstName": "**********",
          "lastName": "**********"
        },
        "purpose": "STANDARD",
        "emailAddress": "**********",
        "phones": [
          {
            "deviceType": "**********",
            "countryCallingCode": "**",
            "number": "**********"
          }
        ],
        "address": {
          "lines": [
            "**********"
          ],
          "postalCode": "**********",
          "cityName": "**********",
          "countryCode": "**********"
        }
      }
    ],
    "remarks": {
      "general": [
        {
          "subType": "GENERAL_MISCELLANEOUS",
          "text": "ONLINE BOOKING FROM INCREIBLE VIAJES"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ticketingAgreement": {
      "option": "DELAY_TO_CANCEL",
      "delay": "6D"
    }
  }
```

and this is my API response.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [status] => 400
                    [code] => 34651
                    [title] => SEGMENT SELL FAILURE
                    [detail] => Could not sell segment 2
                    [source] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [pointer] => /data/flightOffers[0]/itineraries[1]/segments[0]
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

- 

Can you please guide me what is the issue.I am using amadeus test API credential.Also guide me how to solve the issue
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when trying to book a seat that is not available anymore. You are using the test environment, it means everybody else using Amadeus for Developers in test can be trying to book the same seat.

Try with another flight and don't forget to perform the Flight Offers Price before booking.

PS: I see some personal data in the example above, you should edit your post to remove it.

Comment: Thank you given me your valuable response
if seat is not available for booking then how can I remove it from flight offer price search list. because user unable to choose that particular seat from  flight offer price search list
Please guide me

Comment: In theory, if you call Flight Offers Price before Flight Create Orders, you should not face this issue. This will not happen in production, but in test, because of the number of people using the API, it can happen that even if you call Flight Offers Price before and try to book after, the flight doesn't have the seat available anymore as someone else might have booked it.